# SQL BigQuery: Getting Max of a Field over a Range on Another Field

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

The inputs are table `a` that contains time windows of interest, expressed in epoch timestamps, and table `b` that contains the velocity of an object every second.

There are two problems I'm trying to solve using these tables.

(1) For every `start_time` in table `a`, find the maximum velocity in the next 15 seconds from table `b`.

(2) For every time interval expressed as a row in table `a`, find the maximum velocity within the interval.

Table `a`:

| start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- |
| 1679278400 | 1679278415 |
| 1679278448 | 1679278458 |

Table `b`:

| timestamp | velocity |
| --- | --- |
| 1679278405 | 1.543 |
| 1679278406 | 1.683 |

My initial code was along the lines of:

```
with max_vel as (select timestamp, max(velocity) from b
join a
on b.timestamp between a.start_time and a.end_time
group by b.timestamp)
select * from a
left join max_vel
on max_vel.timestamp = a.start_time
```

However this returns multiple rows for each record in `a`.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

For (1)

```
select a.start_time, a.start_time + 15, max(b.velocity) 
from a inner join b on b.timestamp between a.start_time and a.start_time + 
15
group by a.start_time, a.start_time + 15;
```

For (2)

```
select a.start_time, a.end_time, max(b.velocity) 
from a inner join b on b.timestamp between a.start_time and a.end_time
group by a.start_time, a.end_time;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```sql
select a.start_time, 
    (select max(b.velocity)
       from b
      where b.timestamp between a.start_time and a.start_time+15 ) velocity
 from a
```

```sql
select a.start_time, 
    (select max(b.velocity) 
       from b 
      where b.timestamp between a.start_time and a.end_time ) velocity
 from a
```